# Datatype to store date of format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am not knowing which datatype to be assigned to the data of format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?
I use postgresql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `timestamp` (with or without timezone, with timezone preferred to store the actual data)

See [PostgreSQL's documentation on Date/Time Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: timestamp with time zone will work as well, and respect the client's time zone.

Comment: Well I would indeed recommend the use of timezone in stored data, however with timezone it's no longer the requested `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format as you now add timezone.

Comment: `strobel=# create table test (dat timestamptz, info text); 
CREATE TABLE 
strobel=# insert into test values ('2014-02-27 19:07:57','it works'); 
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# select * from test;
          dat           |   info   
------------------------+----------
 2014-02-27 19:07:57+01 | it works `